# My Professor and I are debating about absorption law

Tags: logic-gates, boolean-algebra, computers

So the question is \$(w+y)(wz+wz')wy+y\$ and this is my answer by absorption law where \$A+AB=A\$:

$$
(w+y)(wz+wz!)w  y  +  y\\
      B         A  +  A
$$

So the answer is \$A=y\$.

My professor said I was wrong on using the identity because the long equation can't be considered as one variable.

I said since the long equation is in multiplication, by the rules of basic algebra, it can be considered as one term.

Help me. The picture is attached below

[image]

Comment: Verifying using Mathematica: `BooleanMinimize[((w || y) && (w && z || w && ! z) && (w && y)) || y]` gives `y`. You are right. Please edit and write title in lower-case. And make it about the question, not the prof.

Comment: _"multiplication, by the rules of basic algebra..."_ - ??? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra

Comment: You are right. Aaaand the professor needs training.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about electricity or electronics.

Answer (score 13):

I like the OP's insight better but here is a step by step solution.

```
(W +Y)(W Z + W Z')(W Y) + Y

(W + Y) {W (Z + Z')} (W Y) + Y

(W + Y) {W (1)}( W Y) + Y

(W + Y) (W) (W Y) + Y

(W) (W + Y) (W Y) + Y

(W W + W Y)(W Y) + Y

(W + W Y) (W Y ) + Y

{W(1 + Y)} (W Y) + Y

{W (1)}(W Y)+ Y

W (W Y) + Y

W W Y + Y

W Y + Y

Y (W + 1)

Y (1)

Y
```

Comment: Well, isn't the point there that all of this is totally unnecessary, since we can immediately see that whatever \$ (w+y)(wz+wz')w \$  is, it has no effect on the value of the expression? Now, if the expression turned into \$ (w+y)(wz+xz')wy + y \$  instead (I changed one \$ w \$ to \$ x \$), you'd have to do the step-by-step simplification again, while the insight they've made just gives the result far more simply and quickly.

Comment: Computers don't have insight. They need to do a step by step solution. Hence it is important to know how it is done. To emphasize, the only way out for a computer (perhaps running a synthesis tool) would be a step by step solution even for the simplest of cases. @ilkkachu

Comment: I seriously doubt the poster or their professor is a computer.

Answer (score 5):

You are correct (although it's not 'basic algebra').

You can prove it by exhaustively evaluating for all 8 combinations of W,Y, Z.

Answer (score 4):

You had \$ (w+y)(wz+wz')w y + y \$. Let's group it like \$ [(w+y)(wz+wz')w] y + y \$ and look at the subexpression in the brackets.

If this is boolean algebra, then whatever the values of \$ w, y, z \$ are, **the subexpression \$ (w+y)(wz+wz')w \$ must be either true (1) or false (0).** Not 123, undefined, a cat, or anything else. It can't turn into something completely different just because the expression has a few parts.

So, it has to play by the usual rules, and we can e.g. write a truth table for the whole thing:

| [(w+y)(wz+wz')w] | y | [(w+y)(wz+wz')w] y | [(w+y)(wz+wz')w]y + y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

That's all the possibilities there are. It's rather clear then that the full expression \$ (w+y)(wz+wz')w y + y \$ is equal to \$ y \$.

For the same reason, we could have just given that subexpression some shorter name and saved a bit of typing there, but I guess it might be easier to digest this way (for the professor, I mean).

Now, it's possible they meant this is an exercise or test on other things too, like the subexpression \$ (wz+wz') \$, which also rather obviously simplifies down to \$ w \$. Nothing wrong in that, but it comes to mind they might be a bit miffed about leaving an opening that made it possible to skip a large part of the task they tried to give.

Comment: No, you are right. I missed the extra y.

Comment: @Math, ok, thanks. I tried to clarify the post a bit.

Answer (score 3):

Slightly shorter than Syed's proof is this

```
(W +Y) (W Z + W Z') (W Y) + Y

(W + Y) (W (Z + Z')) (W Y) + Y

(W + Y) (W (1)) (W Y) + Y

(W + Y) W (W Y) + Y

W (W Y) + Y

(W Y) + Y

Y
```

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the level of rigour / appeal to axioms expected of you, your professor may be expecting you to state that logical AND and logical OR are both commutative, so that \$A+AB = BA+A\$, but regardless, you're correct. Let \$A = y\$, \$B = (w+y)(wz+w\overline{z})w\$, then the expression reduces to \$BA+A\$, which equals \$A+AB\$, which equals \$A\$ by the absorption law, which we know is \$y\$.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to learn so many "laws".

Initial expression

$$(w+y) \cdot (w \cdot z+w \cdot \overline{z}) \cdot w \cdot y + y$$

First, apply identity for AND

$$(w+y) \cdot (w \cdot z+w \cdot \overline{z}) \cdot w \cdot y + 1 \cdot y$$

Now, grouping (anti-distributivity)

$$\left[ (w+y) \cdot (w \cdot z+w \cdot \overline{z}) \cdot w + 1 \right] \cdot y$$

Now, the absorbing-point for OR reduces everything inside the brackets

$$\left[ 1 \right] \cdot y$$

And finally identity for AND once again

$$y$$

Done.

You were right not to attempt simplification of any subexpressions left of the \$+ y\$

---

What you have called "absorption law (in two variables)" is a consequence of the absorbing-point for OR, namely
$$\forall x, 1 + x = 1$$

This is the only one of the basic identities of Boolean algebra that is not shared with ordinary algebra (in ordinary arithmetic, addition has no absorbing-point).

There is a similar absorbing-point identity for AND (this one applies to ordinary multiplication of course)
$$\forall x, 0 \cdot x = 0$$

The great thing about these absorbing points is that they absorb *any expression*, not just a simple variable.

Comment: 'You don't need to learn so many "laws".' — Depending on who you ask, the absorption law is a defining property of Boolean algebra, not merely an emergent theorem, so it is reasonable to expect it be known by those studying it.

Comment: @JivanPal: But it can be proved using simpler properties, and it's quite perverse to choose a complicated basis set when a simpler one works just as well.  Particularly because the simpler properties appear elsewhere in abstract algebras, such as groups and fields (two operators denoted \$A+B\$ and \$A \cdot B\$, with commutivity, distributivity, and identity elements for each operator), sets (negation \$\overline A\$, exclusivity of \$A \cup \overline A = {\bf 0}\$, coverage of \$A \cap \overline A = \Omega\$), and then theory of Markov chains gives us absorbing states.

Comment: I said "depending on who you ask", because you can also formulate Boolean algebra as just a bounded lattice with distributivity of × over +, and the absorption law is a defining property of a (bounded) lattice. "Simpler" is subjective. If you use "simpler" to mean "having fewer axioms", then [see here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_axioms_for_Boolean_algebra).